# Angularjs get indexOf through filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a set of JSON data returned by the backend API, and i need to loop through existing array and get the `index` to be used in `splice`, thus i am using `indexOf` method combined with the filter function from angular.

I am able to filter the data out from existing array, however i am unable to get the index of the array, it returned `-1`.

This is how do it.

**JS**

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(){
   var index = $scope.Tablelist.indexOf($filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true));
   console.log($filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true));
   console.log(index);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$filter` returns an array, from which you need to get the first element, and then search with `indexOf`:

```
var index = $scope.Tablelist.indexOf(
                $filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true)[0]
            );
```

However, I would just use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). It will be much faster, since it won't iterate the `Tablelist` more than it needs to.

```
var index = $scope.Tablelist.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.id === $scope.data.id;
});
```

Or a regular `for` loop if you want better browser compatibility:

```
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Tablelist.length; i++)
    if ($scope.Tablelist[i].id === $scope.data.id) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: care to explain why you would use findIndex instead of filter?

Comment: For speed. With the `filter` method, it will iterate the `Tablelist` twice. Once to find the correct item with the `filter`, and again in the `indexOf`. With `findIndex` it will only iterate once, and it will only be until it finds the first match.

Comment: A warning actually. I just realized that `findIndex` isn't supported in IE or Opera. You might be better off just using a `for` loop with a `break` when it finds a match.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
var object = $filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist, function (d) {
   return d.id === $scope.data.id;
})[0]
console.log(object);
console.log($scope.Tablelist.indexOf(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true)
```

Returns a an array of length 1, not the item itself.

```
$filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true)[0]
```

may do the trick

Answer (score 1):

`$filter` returns an array, you are trying to find index of that array in your `Tablelist` which returns -1, try:

```
var index =
  $scope.Tablelist.indexOf($filter('filter')($scope.Tablelist,{id: $scope.data.id},true)[0]));
```